# Issue Verifying Off-chain Signatures with ed25519_dalek and salty Libraries in Solana Program

Tags: signature, publickey

I'm facing an issue when trying to verify off-chain signatures in my Solana program using the ed25519_dalek library. The same problem occurs with the salty library when attempting to convert a PublicKey. The error arises at the line where I try to convert byte array into a PublicKey using PublicKey::from_bytes(&public_key_bytes).unwrap(). Here's the code snippet:

The error message is:

> Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed:
> Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete

```
use ed25519_dalek::{PublicKey, Signature, Verifier};

pub fn release_token(
        ctx: Context<ReleaseTokenTransfer>,
        amount: u64,
        tx_hash: [u8; 32],
        signature: [u8; 64],
        authority: Pubkey
    ) -> Result<()> {
        
        let raw_message = TokenTransferMsg{
            program: ctx.program_id.key(),
            tx_hash: tx_hash,
            mint_token: ctx.accounts.mint_token_account.key(),
            to: ctx.accounts.to_account.key(),
            amount: amount
        };
        let mut message: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        raw_message.serialize(&mut message).unwrap();

        // Hash the message using SHA-256, as required by ed25519
        let mut hasher = Sha256::new();
        hasher.update(&message);
        let hashed_message = hasher.finalize();

        // Convert the signature and authority (public key) into the required format
        let signature = Signature::from_bytes(&signature).unwrap();
        let public_key_bytes = authority.to_bytes(); // Convert the authority into bytes
        let public_key = PublicKey::from_bytes(&public_key_bytes).unwrap();

        // // to do: double check this project: https://github.com/ycrypto/salty
        // // let key = salty::signature::PublicKey::try_from(&authority.to_bytes()).unwrap();
        // // let sig = salty::signature::Signature::from(&signature);

        // // Verify the signature
        // public_key.verify(&hashed_message, &signature)
        // .map_err(|_| error!(BridgeError::InvalidSignature))?;

        Ok(())
    }
```

My environment details:

```
$ rustup -V
rustup 1.26.0 (5af9b9484 2023-04-05)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)`
$ rustc -V
rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)
$ cargo -V 
cargo 1.75.0 (1d8b05cdd 2023-11-20)
$ solana -V
solana-cli 1.18.1 (src:5d824a36; feat:756280933, client:SolanaLabs)
$ anchor -V
anchor-cli 0.29.0
```

```
[package]
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.29.0", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
anchor-spl = "0.29.0"
ed25519-dalek = "1.0.1"
sha2 = "0.9"
```

Pls note that my Cargo.toml includes ed25519-dalek version 1.0.1 and sha2 version 0.9. I had to downgrade ed25519-dalek due to dependency resolution issues with latest version requiring resolver = "2".

Can anyone help me figure out and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the high compute requires, you won't be able to verify signatures directly inside your Solana program using the dalek crate. The runtime does, however, expose a program for verifying ed25519 signatures.

You can learn more about the program at https://docs.solanalabs.com/runtime/programs#ed25519-program, how to use it at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/sdk/src/ed25519_instruction.rs, and some tests at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/programs/ed25519-tests/tests/process_transaction.rs. Here's an example using it:

```
    let privkey = generate_keypair();
    let message_arr = b"hello";
    let instruction = new_ed25519_instruction(&privkey, message_arr);

    let transaction = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
        &[instruction],
        Some(&payer.pubkey()),
        &[payer],
        recent_blockhash,
    );
```